# Node.js Passport login method shows cannot read property 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

Files:

- [Server.js](https://pastebin.com/xGXUXkRG)
- [app.js](https://pastebin.com/zk3yiWbb)

So I've added a passport login method and the following snippet is there in the app.js

```
require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

but I'm hitting the following error and even after google search I don't know what causes it to occour:

```
nodemon
[nodemon] 1.17.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option app.js:30:9express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option;     provide saveUninitialized option app.js:30:9
B:\Shall\Practice\tryBlog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:140
  var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?');
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.handle (B:\Shall\Practice\tryBlog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:140:28)
    at router (B:\Shall\Practice\tryBlog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (B:\Shall\Practice\tryBlog\app.js:38:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (B:\Shall\Practice\tryBlog\server.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What things should I know to cure this?

Comment: `req.url` is `undefined` ?! Maybe include the related codepart ?!

Comment: @JonasW. but that's inside node_modules which come with the installation, and why would I even touch it?

Comment: No, its in `tryBlog\app.js:38:28`, express just catches and rethrows.

Comment: @JonasW.  no it is in `tryBlog\node_modules` the error it shows is in `app.js` as you said, and it is where it occurs at ```require('./routes/blog')(app, passport);```